# mysql loop error in syntax

Tags: mysql, loops, label

I am trying to use simple loop in mysql using Heidisql using the following syntax.

```
BEGIN
loop_label:  LOOP
                     IF  @number_title  > @max THEN
                          **LEAVE  loop_label;**
                     END  IF;
select @number_title as number_distinct_title,count(*) as total from (
select count(distinct ctitle), customer_id
FROM table
GROUP BY customer_id
HAVING count(distinct ctitle)=@number_title 
ORDER BY customer_id) as total ;
SET @number_title = @number_title + 1;
END LOOP
END
```

I get a syntax error at **LEAVE  loop_label;**

Can someone please help?

Thanks

Comment: Can you tell us what you are trying to achieve and perhaps put a sample output for us?  We may be able to give you a more standard sql statement to do what you're after without you having to suffer LOOP-aches

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL when you define a trigger or procedure, you usually have to change the delimiter temporarily, because statements within the trigger/procedure must be terminated with ';'.

Just enclose the complete block in "--/" and "/" and you should be good

```
--/
BEGIN
loop_label:  LOOP
                 IF  @number_title  > @max THEN
                      **LEAVE  loop_label;**
                 END  IF;
 select @number_title as number_distinct_title,count(*) as total from (
 select count(distinct ctitle), customer_id
 FROM table
 GROUP BY customer_id
 HAVING count(distinct ctitle)=@number_title 
 ORDER BY customer_id) as total ;
 SET @number_title = @number_title + 1;
 END LOOP
END
 /
```

Found from [Here](http://www.dbvis.com/forum/thread.jspa?threadID=2217&tstart=5&messageID=12690)

Comment: Hi RGG, I included the code snippet within --/ and / and still I get the same error : SQL Error (1064) : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '--/ BEGIN loop_label LOOP if @NUMBER_TITLE >@MAX

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: is it really necissary to have the 'Jump' statement in there.  Would an if--else--if else-- style not work just the same, and be easier to support?

I also recommend checking out something like dbvisualizer maybe it's a heidisql problem?